# Odd ip2nation database record with Seychelles and Syria?

Tags: mysql, sql

The [ip2nation](http://www.ip2nation.com/) database is confusing me:

```
code    iso_code_2  iso_code_3  iso_country     country 
----------------------------------------------------------
sy      SY          SYC         Seychelles      Seychelles
sc      SY          SYC         Seychelles      Syria
```

What's up with this?

**UPDATE:**

I've gone ahead and corrected some of this (Seychelles = sc & SC; Syria = sy, SY, Syrian Arab Republic), but still am unsure what the iso_code_3 should be. The database author has been e-mailed.

Comment: @OMG Thanks for the formatting. Somethings amiss here. Wikipedia says: Seychelles is ISO 3166 code SC, Internet TLD .sc. Wondering if anyone could verify what these entries should properly read

Answer (score 2):

Iso_code_3 for Syria = SYR
Iso_code_3 for Seychelles = SYC

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is wrong. You can notify them.

`.sy` is TLD extension of Syria. Maybe Syria has a small city named Seychelles, but it does not seem so according to Google.

Comment: Yes, there is clearly some mix-up here. Wikipedia's got Syria's Internet TLD as .sy?? -- I've e-mailed the site admin.

Comment: syria is .sy, seychelles is .sc